# Need to convert this SQL to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I've got this SQL, but I need to convert it to a Linq query. Having difficulty trying to use partition/rownum and patition/count together.

```
Select TOP 1 vals.c3, (vals.Rank * vals.[Occurances]) as RNK
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1 asc) as Rank, Count(*) Over(Partition By c3) As [Occurances], c3
FROM dbo.ranks
WHERE c2 in ('ADAMS', 'CHIP', 'SHOP')
group by  c3,c2,c1
) vals
--group by vals.c3
ORDER BY RNK desc
```

This is what the ranks list will look like:

```
c1      c2      c3
26774   CHIP     Chipshop
26054   SHOP     Shops
10054   SHOP     Chipshop
23037   MEDICAL  Doctors
21434   CENTRE   Doctors
12803   DENTAL   Dentists
11847   OFFICE   Post Offices
```

c2 is the word, c3 is the category i'm looking for. c1 is how often that word occurs per category. So when I enter search for 'Adams Chip shop', it'll go and find the most likely category match based on that name.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool. It does exactly what you want.

[Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)